# MySQL connection freeze the runtime

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried almost every possible MySQL Server running on my computer or on the web server, And every connection causes the PHP Runtime to freeze. Any workout/solutions for that?

```
$mydbsql = mysql_pconnect("localhost:3301", "local", "local") or die("It doesn't even die");
 or...
 $mydbsql = mysql_pconnect("localhost:3306", "local", "local") or die("It doesn't even die");
  or...
  $mydbsql = mysql_pconnect("localhost:4430", "local", "local") or die("It doesn't even die");
```

Debugging the code shows that every line before running the connect function works fine but when It gets to the connection, It freeze the runtime (stucks at loading).

**Edit:** Just waited a long time and after that an error popped up.

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     FastCgiModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    php-5.6.1
Error Code     0x80070102
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your mysql use port 3301 or port 3306?
It might be that the port is wrong in your example?

Answer (score 0):

By MySQL and Linux or even Windows MySQL always runs on port 3306.